# Unable to navigate to the next page when clicking button using intent in android app

Tags: android, android-intent

This is my XML layout code for login page button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/googleLogin"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/logoImage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:background="#d34836"
        android:text="@string/google_login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/post_gplus"
        android:paddingLeft="12sp"
        android:paddingRight="12sp"
        android:drawablePadding="5sp"
        android:onClick="clickLoginGoogle"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/facebookLogin"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/googleLogin"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/googleLogin"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/googleLogin"
        android:background="#4267b2"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/post_facebook"
        android:text="@string/facebook_login"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="12sp"
        android:paddingRight="12sp"
        android:drawablePadding="5sp"
        android:onClick="clickLoginFacebook"/>
```

this is my java code for login page:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class LoginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    public void clickLoginFacebook(View view1)
    {
        toastMsg(" Logged in through Facebook!!");


        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,UserDetail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void clickLoginGoogle(View view1)
    {

        toastMsg(" Logged in through Google");

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginScreen.this,UserDetail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void toastMsg(String msg) {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);


    }
}
```

This is the xml code for the screen I want to transition to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.blahblah.testapp.UserDetail">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Name:"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="113dp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:text="Email:" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        tools:text="Age:"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        tools:text="Gender:"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        tools:text="Location:"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="269dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        tools:text="Optional"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#616161"
        tools:text="Date of Birth:"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#9e9e9e"
        tools:text="(Get special offers on your birthday)"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my manifest code:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserDetail"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:label="UserDetail" >



        </activity>
    </application>
```

The name of the login page is LoginScreen and the name of the page I want to transition to is UserDetail

When I press on the button all I am getting is a black blank screen not the userdetail page I am designing. Can someone tell me what is the problem?

this is my logcat log when I click on the buttons:

```
    12-13 20:08:25.236 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.245 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.281 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.345 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.396 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.411 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:25.509 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
12-13 20:08:39.174 2423-2443/io.blahblah.testapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb429dac0: ver 2 0
```

The login screen I want to transition from https://i.stack.imgur.com/8340W.jpg

The screen I want to transition to https://i.stack.imgur.com/9POiX.jpg

The screen I am getting when I press the button https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QFOY.jpg

Comment: post UserDetail.class ,

Comment: can you update UserDetail.class code?

Comment: 'import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_detail);
    }
}'

Comment: I see that in your UserDetail class xml class, you have added `tools:text`. Try replacing it with `android:text`. Hope it hepls!

Comment: userdetail is a blank activity right now . i didnt do much to it . im not sure if i have to do something in the java codes to just transiton from the loginscreen to userdetail screen . thats where im stuck at right now .

Comment: @chithra  Hey that was it. now i see the text .. Thank you so much :) is tools:text depricated or something or is it just wrong usage?

Comment: Glad that i helped you !

Comment: Nope, it is used just for the layout preview.

Comment: @chithra  layout preview huh .. well il keep that in mind and i think i best delete this question since its not an issue with intent like i thought .. Its more xml based . Thanks again .

Comment: @Parag could u please vote my answer if its helped. Thank u!

Comment: @Chithra sure .. could you type down your comment as an answer . Im not sure how to vote yes for a comment . If you could type it down like the other two guys who answered it, il tick it as the right answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `android:text` instead `tools:text`

`tools:text` : This is used only for the layout preview to review the design, it will not be displayed when you run the application.

`android:text` : The text will be displayed when you run the application.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if this is not working

Alternative-:

```
Button facebook=(Button)findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);

facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener)
{
   Do watever you want

});
}
```

Comment: sorry guys . it turns out its not an issue with intent .  I used tool:text instead of android:text so the text was not visible even though the transition happened . Il remove this question so as not to confuse anyone since Intent worked exaclty as it should(looks like i cant delete the question )

Answer (score 0):

Give complete path to activity class in manifest.

For ex: Suppose that your activity is inside to app package under src so use path like below in XML

```
<activity
            android:name=".app.ActivityMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeHideStatusbar" />
```

Hoping this might solve your problem.